# Python natural smoothing splines

Tags: python, regression, spline, smoothing

I am trying to find a python package that would give an option to fit *natural smoothing splines* with user selectable smoothing factor. Is there an implementation for that? If not, how would you use what is available to implement it yourself?

- By natural spline I mean that there should be a condition that the second derivative of the fitted function at the endpoints is zero (linear).
- By smoothing spline I mean that the spline should not be 'interpolating' (passing through all the datapoints). I would like to decide the correct smoothing factor lambda (see the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing_spline) for smoothing splines) myself.

### What I have found

- scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline [[link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline)]: Does natural (cubic) spline fitting. Does interpolation, and there is no way to smooth the data.
- scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline [[link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline)]: Does spline fitting with user selectable smoothing factor. However, there is no option to make the splines natural.

Answer (score 45):

After hours of investigation, I did not find any pip installable packages which could fit a natural cubic spline with user-controllable smoothness. However, after deciding to write one myself, while reading about the topic I stumbled upon a [blog post](http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2017/08/04/basis-expansions.html) by github user [madrury](https://github.com/madrury). He has written python code capable of producing natural cubic spline models.

The model code is available [here](https://github.com/madrury/basis-expansions/blob/master/basis_expansions/basis_expansions.py) (NaturalCubicSpline) with [a BSD-licence](https://github.com/madrury/basis-expansions/blob/master/LICENSE). He has also written some examples in an [IPython notebook](https://github.com/madrury/basis-expansions/blob/master/examples/basis-expansion-regressions.ipynb).

But since this is the Internet and links tend to die, I will copy the relevant parts of the source code here + a helper function (`get_natural_cubic_spline_model`) written by me, and show an example of how to use it. The smoothness of the fit can be controlled by using different number of knots. The position of the knots can be also specified by the user.

### Example

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    return 1/(1+25*x**2)

# make example data
x = np.linspace(-1,1,300)
y = func(x) + np.random.normal(0, 0.2, len(x))

# The number of knots can be used to control the amount of smoothness
model_6 = get_natural_cubic_spline_model(x, y, minval=min(x), maxval=max(x), n_knots=6)
model_15 = get_natural_cubic_spline_model(x, y, minval=min(x), maxval=max(x), n_knots=15)
y_est_6 = model_6.predict(x)
y_est_15 = model_15.predict(x)


plt.plot(x, y, ls='', marker='.', label='originals')
plt.plot(x, y_est_6, marker='.', label='n_knots = 6')
plt.plot(x, y_est_15, marker='.', label='n_knots = 15')
plt.legend(); plt.show()
```

[image: Example of natural cubic splines with varying smoothness.]

### The source code for `get_natural_cubic_spline_model`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline


def get_natural_cubic_spline_model(x, y, minval=None, maxval=None, n_knots=None, knots=None):
    """
    Get a natural cubic spline model for the data.

    For the knots, give (a) `knots` (as an array) or (b) minval, maxval and n_knots.

    If the knots are not directly specified, the resulting knots are equally
    space within the *interior* of (max, min).  That is, the endpoints are
    *not* included as knots.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x: np.array of float
        The input data
    y: np.array of float
        The outpur data
    minval: float 
        Minimum of interval containing the knots.
    maxval: float 
        Maximum of the interval containing the knots.
    n_knots: positive integer 
        The number of knots to create.
    knots: array or list of floats 
        The knots.

    Returns
    --------
    model: a model object
        The returned model will have following method:
        - predict(x):
            x is a numpy array. This will return the predicted y-values.
    """

    if knots:
        spline = NaturalCubicSpline(knots=knots)
    else:
        spline = NaturalCubicSpline(max=maxval, min=minval, n_knots=n_knots)

    p = Pipeline([
        ('nat_cubic', spline),
        ('regression', LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True))
    ])

    p.fit(x, y)

    return p


class AbstractSpline(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Base class for all spline basis expansions."""

    def __init__(self, max=None, min=None, n_knots=None, n_params=None, knots=None):
        if knots is None:
            if not n_knots:
                n_knots = self._compute_n_knots(n_params)
            knots = np.linspace(min, max, num=(n_knots + 2))[1:-1]
            max, min = np.max(knots), np.min(knots)
        self.knots = np.asarray(knots)

    @property
    def n_knots(self):
        return len(self.knots)

    def fit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self


class NaturalCubicSpline(AbstractSpline):
    """Apply a natural cubic basis expansion to an array.
    The features created with this basis expansion can be used to fit a
    piecewise cubic function under the constraint that the fitted curve is
    linear *outside* the range of the knots..  The fitted curve is continuously
    differentiable to the second order at all of the knots.
    This transformer can be created in two ways:
      - By specifying the maximum, minimum, and number of knots.
      - By specifying the cutpoints directly.  

    If the knots are not directly specified, the resulting knots are equally
    space within the *interior* of (max, min).  That is, the endpoints are
    *not* included as knots.
    Parameters
    ----------
    min: float 
        Minimum of interval containing the knots.
    max: float 
        Maximum of the interval containing the knots.
    n_knots: positive integer 
        The number of knots to create.
    knots: array or list of floats 
        The knots.
    """

    def _compute_n_knots(self, n_params):
        return n_params

    @property
    def n_params(self):
        return self.n_knots - 1

    def transform(self, X, **transform_params):
        X_spl = self._transform_array(X)
        if isinstance(X, pd.Series):
            col_names = self._make_names(X)
            X_spl = pd.DataFrame(X_spl, columns=col_names, index=X.index)
        return X_spl

    def _make_names(self, X):
        first_name = "{}_spline_linear".format(X.name)
        rest_names = ["{}_spline_{}".format(X.name, idx)
                      for idx in range(self.n_knots - 2)]
        return [first_name] + rest_names

    def _transform_array(self, X, **transform_params):
        X = X.squeeze()
        try:
            X_spl = np.zeros((X.shape[0], self.n_knots - 1))
        except IndexError: # For arrays with only one element
            X_spl = np.zeros((1, self.n_knots - 1))
        X_spl[:, 0] = X.squeeze()

        def d(knot_idx, x):
            def ppart(t): return np.maximum(0, t)

            def cube(t): return t*t*t
            numerator = (cube(ppart(x - self.knots[knot_idx]))
                         - cube(ppart(x - self.knots[self.n_knots - 1])))
            denominator = self.knots[self.n_knots - 1] - self.knots[knot_idx]
            return numerator / denominator

        for i in range(0, self.n_knots - 2):
            X_spl[:, i+1] = (d(i, X) - d(self.n_knots - 2, X)).squeeze()
        return X_spl
```

Comment: @np8 is this an accurate way to fit the model considering only train data? model_6 = get_natural_cubic_spline_model(X_train, y_train, minval=min(X_train), maxval=max(X_train), n_knots=6), where X_train and y_train are X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False)

Answer (score 25):

You could use [this numpy/scipy implementation](https://github.com/espdev/csaps) of natural cubic smoothing spline for univariate/multivariate data smoothing. Smoothing parameter should be in range [0.0, 1.0]. If we use smoothing parameter equal to 1.0 we get natural cubic spline interpolant without data smoothing. Also the implementation supports vectorization for univariate data.

Univariate example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import csaps

np.random.seed(1234)

x = np.linspace(-5., 5., 25)
y = np.exp(-(x/2.5)**2) + (np.random.rand(25) - 0.2) * 0.3

sp = csaps.UnivariateCubicSmoothingSpline(x, y, smooth=0.85)

xs = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 150)
ys = sp(xs)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', xs, ys, '-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Bivariate example:

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

import csaps

xdata = [np.linspace(-3, 3, 61), np.linspace(-3.5, 3.5, 51)]
i, j = np.meshgrid(*xdata, indexing='ij')

ydata = (3 * (1 - j)**2. * np.exp(-(j**2) - (i + 1)**2)
         - 10 * (j / 5 - j**3 - i**5) * np.exp(-j**2 - i**2)
         - 1 / 3 * np.exp(-(j + 1)**2 - i**2))

np.random.seed(12345)
noisy = ydata + (np.random.randn(*ydata.shape) * 0.75)

sp = csaps.MultivariateCubicSmoothingSpline(xdata, noisy, smooth=0.988)
ysmth = sp(xdata)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot_wireframe(j, i, noisy, linewidths=0.5, color='r')
ax.scatter(j, i, noisy, s=5, c='r')

ax.plot_surface(j, i, ysmth, linewidth=0, alpha=1.0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The `csaps` looks great! One thing to note is that at least in v. 0.11.0 the `csaps.csaps()` needs unique x-values. I ended up having a preprocess step to calculate averages for the non-unique x-values.

Comment: @np8, x-values must be unique and strictly monotonic. You need to use multivariate smoothing with parametrization ```xs = u(x), ys = v(y)``` if you have non-unique or/and non-monotonic x-values.

Comment: I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'csaps' has no attribute 'MultivariateCubicSmoothingSpline'` and I cannot find why!

Comment: @sam, please read the current documentation. https://csaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @iroln Thanks for your comment. I am still not able to solve the problem. In the documentation there is no code or example for multivariate case (there's just a figure!). Changing `import csaps` to `from csaps import csaps` also did not help.

Comment: @sam You can just use csaps function or CubicSmoothingSpline class for multivariate case. See the section: https://csaps.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#multivariate-smoothing

Answer (score 17):

The python package patsy has functions for generating spline bases, including a natural cubic spline basis. Described in the [documentation](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html#spline-regression).
Any library can then be used for fitting a model, e.g. scikit-learn or statsmodels.

- The `df` parameter for `cr()` can be used to control the "smoothness"
- Note that too low `df` can result to underfit (see below).

A simple example using scikit-learn.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from patsy import cr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_obs = 600
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, n_obs)
y = 1 / (x ** 2 + 1) * np.cos(np.pi * x) + np.random.normal(0, 0.2, size=n_obs)


def plot_smoothed(df=5):

    # Generate spline basis with different degrees of freedom
    x_basis = cr(x, df=df, constraints="center")

    # Fit model to the data
    model = LinearRegression().fit(x_basis, y)

    # Get estimates
    y_hat = model.predict(x_basis)

    plt.plot(x, y_hat, label=f"df={df}")


plt.scatter(x, y, s=4, color="tab:blue")

for df in (5, 7, 10, 25):
    plot_smoothed(df)

plt.legend()
plt.title(f"Natural cubic spline with varying degrees of freedom")
plt.show()
```

[image: example splines]

Answer (score 12):

For a project of mine, I needed to create intervals for time-series modeling, and to make the procedure more efficient I created [tsmoothie](https://github.com/cerlymarco/tsmoothie): A python library for time-series smoothing and outlier detection in a vectorized way.

It provides different smoothing algorithms together with the possibility to computes intervals.

In the case of `SplineSmoother` of natural cubic type:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tsmoothie.smoother import *

def func(x):
    return 1/(1+25*x**2)

# make example data
x = np.linspace(-1,1,300)
y = func(x) + np.random.normal(0, 0.2, len(x))

# operate smoothing
smoother = SplineSmoother(n_knots=10, spline_type='natural_cubic_spline')
smoother.smooth(y)

# generate intervals
low, up = smoother.get_intervals('prediction_interval', confidence=0.05)

# plot the first smoothed timeseries with intervals
plt.figure(figsize=(11,6))
plt.plot(smoother.smooth_data[0], linewidth=3, color='blue')
plt.plot(smoother.data[0], '.k')
plt.fill_between(range(len(smoother.data[0])), low[0], up[0], alpha=0.3)
```

[image]

I point out also that tsmoothie can carry out the smoothing of multiple time-series in a vectorized way

Answer (score 4):

The programming language R offers a very good implementation of natural cubic smoothing splines. You can use R functions in Python with `rpy2`:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r_y = robjects.FloatVector(y_train)
r_x = robjects.FloatVector(x_train)

r_smooth_spline = robjects.r['smooth.spline'] #extract R function# run smoothing function
spline1 = r_smooth_spline(x=r_x, y=r_y, spar=0.7)
ySpline=np.array(robjects.r['predict'](spline1,robjects.FloatVector(x_smooth)).rx2('y'))
plt.plot(x_smooth,ySpline)
```

<sub>If you want to directly set `lambda`: `spline1 = r_smooth_spline(x=r_x, y=r_y, lambda=42)` doesn't work, because `lambda` has already another meaning in Python, but there is a solution: [How to use the lambda argument of smooth.spline in RPy WITHOUT Python interprating it as lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239011/how-to-use-the-lambda-argument-of-smooth-spline-in-rpy-without-python-interprati).</sub>

<sub>To get the code running you first need to define the data `x_train` and `y_train` and you can define `x_smooth=np.array(np.linspace(-3,5,1920)).` if you want to plot it between -3 and 5 in Full-HD-resolution.</sub>

<sub>Note that this code is not fully compatible with Jupyter-notebooks for the latest versions of `rpy2`. You can fix this by using `!pip install -Iv rpy2==3.4.2` as described in [NotImplementedError: Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type '<class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpClosure'>' only after I run the code twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74678378/notimplementederror-conversion-rpy2py-not-defined-for-objects-of-type-class/74678766#74678766)</sub>