# Python SciPy UnivariateSpline vs R smooth.spline

Tags: python, r, scipy, spline

I am porting a script written in R over to Python. In R I am using smooth.spline and in Python I am using SciPy UnivariateSpline. They don't produce the same results (even though they are both based on a cubic spline method). Is there a way, or an alternative to UnivariateSpline, to make the Python spline return the same spline as R?

I'm a mathematician. I understand the general idea of splines. But not the fine details of their implementation in Python or R.

Here is the code in R and then Python. The input data is the same for both.

Here is the input data:

```
x =  0.0,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4,  0.5,  0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9,  1.0
y =   -1,    1,    1,   -1,    1,    0,   .5,   .5,   .4,   .5,   -1
```

Here is the R code

```
x = seq(0,1, by = .1); 
y = c(-1,1,1, -1,1,0, .5,.5,.4,  .5, -1);
spline_xy = smooth.spline(x,y)
predict(spline_xy,x)
```

which outputs:

```
$x
 [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0

$y
 [1]  0.120614583  0.170800975  0.210954680  0.238032338  0.253672155
 [6]  0.253684815  0.236432643  0.200264536  0.145403302  0.074993797
[11] -0.004853825
```

Here is the Python Code

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num = 11, endpoint=True)    
y = np.array([-1,1,1, -1,1,0, .5,.5,.4,  .5, -1]) 
spline_xy = UnivariateSpline(x,y)
print('x =', x)
print('ysplined =',spline_xy(x))
```

which outputs:

```
x = [0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1. ]

ysplined = 
[-0.26433566 -0.02587413  0.18857809 0.36585082  0.49277389  
  0.55617716 0.54289044  0.43974359  0.23356643 -0.08881119 
 -0.54055944]
```

I hoped the outputs, in R $y and in Python ysplined would be identical. But they aren't.

Any help, for example how to set the parameters, or explanations would be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Those appear to me to be different smoothing methods.

`smooth.spline` in R is a "smoothing spline", which is an overparametrized natural spline (knots at every data point, cubic spline in the interior, linear extrapolation), with penalized least squares used to choose the parameters.  You can read the help page for the details of how the penalty is computed.

On the other hand, Python's `UnivariateSpline` appears from the documentation here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline.html to be a regression spline, fit by least squares with no penalty.  It appears to adaptively choose the number of knots.

These are completely different algorithms, and I wouldn't expect them to give equal results.
I don't know if there's an R package that uses the same adaptive choice of knots as Python does.  This answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55481248/2554330  claims to reference a natural smoothing spline implementation in Python, but I don't know if it matches R's implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use R functions in Python with `rpy2`:

```
import numpy as np
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
x = np.linspace(0, 1, num = 11, endpoint=True)    
y = np.array([-1,1,1, -1,1,0, .5,.5,.4,  .5, -1])

r_x = robjects.FloatVector(x)
r_y = robjects.FloatVector(y)
r_smooth_spline = robjects.r['smooth.spline'] #extract R function
spline_xy = r_smooth_spline(x=r_x, y=r_y)
print('x =', x)
print('ysplined =',np.array(robjects.r['predict'](spline_xy,robjects.FloatVector(x)).rx2('y')))
```

which outputs:

```
x = [0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1. ]
ysplined = [ 0.12061458  0.17080098  0.21095468  0.23803234  0.25367215  0.25368481
0.23643264  0.20026454  0.1454033   0.0749938  -0.00485382]
```

exactly like you wished it.

<sub>If you want to directly set `lambda`: `spline_xy = r_smooth_spline(x=r_x, y=r_y, lambda=42)` doesn't work, because `lambda` has already another meaning in Python, but there is a solution: [How to use the lambda argument of smooth.spline in RPy WITHOUT Python interprating it as lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58239011/how-to-use-the-lambda-argument-of-smooth-spline-in-rpy-without-python-interprati).</sub>

<sub>Note that this code is not fully compatible with Jupyter-notebooks for the latest versions of `rpy2`. You can fix this by using `!pip install -Iv rpy2==3.4.2` as described in [NotImplementedError: Conversion 'rpy2py' not defined for objects of type '<class 'rpy2.rinterface.SexpClosure'>' only after I run the code twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74678378/notimplementederror-conversion-rpy2py-not-defined-for-objects-of-type-class/74678766#74678766)</sub>