# How to use the lambda argument of smooth.spline in RPy WITHOUT Python interprating it as lambda

Tags: python, r, rpy2, spline, smoothing

I want to use the natural cubic smoothing splines `smooth.spline` from R in Python (like som many others want as well ([Python natural smoothing splines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51321100/python-natural-smoothing-splines), [Is there a Python equivalent to the smooth.spline function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312005/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-the-smooth-spline-function-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Python SciPy UnivariateSpline vs R smooth.spline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56667657/python-scipy-univariatespline-vs-r-smooth-spline/58239456#58239456), ...))
Therefore I am using `rpy2` like described in https://morioh.com/p/eb4151821dc4, but I want to set directly `lambda` instead of `spar`:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r_y = robjects.FloatVector(y_train)
r_x = robjects.FloatVector(x_train)

r_smooth_spline = robjects.r['smooth.spline'] #extract R function# run smoothing function
spline1 = r_smooth_spline(x=r_x, y=r_y, lambda=42)
#alternative: spline1 = r_smooth_spline(x=r_x, y=r_y, spar=0.7) would work fine, but I would like to control lambda dirctly
ySpline=np.array(robjects.r['predict'](spline1,robjects.FloatVector(x_smooth)).rx2('y'))
plt.plot(x_smooth,ySpline)
```

When I do this the line `spline1 = r_smooth_spline(x=r_x, y=r_y, lambda=42)` doesn't work because Python has already a predefined interpretation of `lambda` (you can see this from the blue code-highlighting of `lambda`) :(
I want `lambda` to be interpreted as the smoothing penalty parameter lambda.

If I replace `lambda` by `spar` I would get a natural cubic spline, but I want to control `lambda` directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This little trick will work around the specific problem you're having, by allowing you to write "lambda" in a string.

```py
kwargs = {"x": r_x, "y": r_y, "lambda":  42}
spline1 = r_smooth_spline(**kwargs)
```

In the general case, you can pass around argument containers easily with tuples and dicts.

```py
# as normal
f = function("foo", "bar", my_kwarg="my_value")

# the same call using argument containers
args = ("foo", "bar")
kwargs = {"my_kwarg": "my_value"}
f = function(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could use `rpy2`'s [Function.rcall()](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/robjects_functions.html#rcall) method when calling `smooth.spline`?

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
r_y = robjects.FloatVector(y_train)
r_x = robjects.FloatVector(x_train)

r_smooth_spline = robjects.r['smooth.spline']
args = (('x',r_x), ('y',r_y), ('lambda',42)) # pattern (('argname', value),...)

# import R's "GlobalEnv" to evaluate the function
from rpy2.robjects import globalenv

spline1 = r_smooth_spline.rcall(args, globalenv)
```

Comment: This a link to outdated documentation. You'll want  https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/robjects_functions.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python's `**<dict>` in a function call to specify R named arguments that have a name that is not syntactically valid in Python.

See the documentation for more details: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.2.x/html/robjects_functions.html

Comment: code example? How would the line `spline1 = r_smooth_spline(x=r_x, y=r_y, lambda=42)` look like when I use `**<dict>`?
`spline1 = r_smooth_spline(x=r_x, y=r_y, **<lambda>=42)` doesn't work...

Comment: Check the doc. Code examples are there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58240214/7735095 added a nice code example. I think that corresponds to your documentation.

Comment: Both answers entered after mine are in the documentation ;-)